Nuxt firebase deployment error: npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform
I am trying to deploy my Nuxt 3 website to firebase using GitHub actions but it failed with the following error:

Note: The deployment was working well with version: 20240225.1.0 of ubuntu-22.04

Other logs here...
i  hosting: upload complete
✔  hosting[magpiethebrand]: file upload complete
i  functions: updating Node.js 18 (2nd Gen) function nuxt:server(europe-west3)...
Build failed with status: FAILURE and message: npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for @css-inline/css-inline-linux-x64-musl@0.12.1: wanted {"os":"linux","cpu":"x64","libc":"musl"} (current: {"os":"linux","cpu":"x64","libc":"glibc"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid os:    linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual os:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Valid cpu:   x64
npm ERR! notsup Actual cpu:  x64
npm ERR! notsup Valid libc:  musl
npm ERR! notsup Actual libc: glibc

The @css-inline/css-inline-linux-x64-musl@0.12.1 is only declared in my package-lock.json file.
Here is my workflow:
name: firebase Continuous Deployment

on:
  push:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
      - uses: actions/setup-node@master
        with:
          node-version: 20
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build
      - uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with: 
          args: deploy
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}

I am using the following dependencies:
"dependencies": {
    "@firebase/app-types": "^0.9.0",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.5.1",
    "firebase": "^10.8.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^12.1.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.7.0",
    "nuxt": "^3.10.3",
    "pinia": "^2.1.7",
    "vue": "^3.4.19",
    "vue-router": "^4.3.0",
    "vue3-toastify": "^0.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@formkit/auto-animate": "^0.8.1",
    "@nuxt/image": "^1.3.0",
    "@nuxtjs/seo": "^2.0.0-rc.8",
    "@nuxtjs/sitemap": "^5.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^6.11.4",
    "daisyui": "^4.7.2",
    "nuxt-gtag": "^2.0.4",
    "nuxt-mdi": "^1.1.6",
    "sass": "^1.71.1",
    "sass-loader": "^14.1.1"
  }

I also tried fixing it in the following ways:
name: firebase Continuous Deployment

on:
  push:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: ekidd/rust-musl-builder:stable
      options: --privileged
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
      - uses: actions/setup-node@master
        with:
          node-version: 20
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build
      - uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with: 
          args: deploy
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}

I added a container image as instructed by chatGPT but got the following error:
/__e/node20/bin/node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /__e/node20/bin/node)

How can I fix this?
How can I use my own custom Image: ubuntu-22.04 Version: 20240225.1.0? Step by step instructions to do this will be highly appreciated, I don't have much experience with docker and images.

You are using a package @css-inline/css-inline-linux-x64-musl that is made for linux systems that use musl (a C library) but your job runs on a ubuntu-latest that uses glibc (another C library).
Then, you tried to use a container that uses musl, but node itself needs glibc.
I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve with this @css-inline/css-inline-linux-x64-musl package (why use C to inline-css in a javascript project?) but I recommend you remove it and you use Nuxt own way to inline css. More info here.
If this doesn't work for you maybe you should choose a different architecture for the package.

The @css-inline/css-inline-linux-x64-musl package is declared in package-lock.json file. Let me add more details on my project setup.
